# XML assigned to SqlXml parameter got extra-encoded?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ado.net

The following code passes an XML parameter to a stored procedure. The SqlXml is converted from a string.

```
var range = GetXml("<Range><Column Name=\"Id\" Low=\"5002\" High=\"8076\" /></Range>");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Range", SqlDbType.Xml) { Value = range });

SqlXml GetXml(string s)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteString(s);
        return new SqlXml(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

However, it turns out the actual XML value passed to the stored procedure is

```
N'&lt;Range&gt;&lt;Column Name="Id" Low="5002" High="8076" /&gt;&lt;/Range&gt;'
```

The value was captured using SQL Server Profiler.

How can I remove the extra encoding of < and >?

Comment: Use : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string);

Comment: It seems it's encoded on the ado.net library. The function won't resolve the issue

Comment: Looks fine to me :             string input = "N'&lt;Range&gt;&lt;Column Name=\"Id\" Low=\"5002\" High=\"8076\" /&gt;&lt;/Range&gt;'";
            string output = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [XmlWriter.WriteString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring(v=vs.110).aspx). The purpose of this method is to add *plain text* content to an element, so the method replaces **&**, **<**, and **>** characters with **&amp;**, **&lt;**, and **&gt;**.

To treat the string as XML instead of plain text, you can create an XmlReader from the string and then pass the XmlReader to the [SqlXml(XmlReader) constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0seyb0cs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// using System.Data.SqlTypes;
// using System.IO;
// using System.Xml;

static SqlXml GetXml(string s)
{
    return new SqlXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(s)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A secure way for casting strings is to use an encoding for example:

```
public static SqlXml GetXml(string s)
{
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(s));
    return new SqlXml(memoryStream);
}
```